# Format string in pandas dataframe cell if it contains a pipe

Tags: python, pandas

I need to read a standard CSV into a data frame, do some manipulations, and stringify the data frame into a specialized pipe separated format (text file). In order to comply with the file format, I have to add double quotes to the entire string in that cell (if it contains a pipe) before writing the final string to a file.

I wanted to leverage [Pandas functions](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/basics.html) to accomplish this. I tried dabbling with the contains and format functions, but have not been successful.

Does anyone know of a simple way to accomplish this leveraging Pandas?

Expected Input:

```
colA,colB,colC,colD
cat,waverly way,foo,10.0
dog,smokey | st,foo,9.7
cow,rapid ave,foo,6.6
rabbit,far | blvd,foo,3.2
```

Expected Output:

```
cat|waverly way|foo|10.0/
dog|"smokey|st"|foo|9.7/
cow|rapid ave|foo|6.6/
rabbit|"far|blvd"|foo|3.2/
```

The "/" is intentional

Comment: Please provide sample input and expected output.

Comment: _I tried dabbling with the contains and format functions, but have not been successful._ Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) & manipulate the matching string as below.

```
df['colB'] = np.where(df['colB'].str.contains('\|'),'"' + df['colB'] + '"' , df['colB'])
```

**Note**: Since only `colB` has the pipe (|) character the code above is written to check only that column & manipulate only that. If pipe (|) character is expected in other columns as well, you may to to repeat the code for other columns as well.

For `colD` you have to convert it into string(if it is not already as string) & add a forward slash as below

```
df['colD'] = df['colD'].astype(str) + '/'
```

**Output**

```
   colA     colB           colC     colD
0   cat     waverly way     foo     10.0/
1   dog     "smokey | st"   foo     9.7/
2   cow     rapid ave       foo     6.6/
3   rabbit  "far | blvd"    foo     3.2/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

test = pd.read_csv("test.csv")

test.to_csv("final.csv", sep="|", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, line_terminator="/\n", header=False, index=False)
```

Here is the contents of "final.csv":

```
"cat"|"waverly way"|"foo"|10.0/
"dog"|"smokey | st"|"foo"|9.7/
"cow"|"rapid ave"|"foo"|6.6/
"rabbit"|"far | blvd"|"foo"|3.2/
```

**Edit:** this will add quotes all non-numeric strings. If you want quotes on only the values with pipes, you can remove the quoting parameter and use moy's solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")

for col in list(df.select_dtypes(include=[object]).columns.values):
  df[col] = np.where(df[col].str.contains('\|') & df[col].str.endswith('"') & df[col].str.startswith('"'),'"' + df[col] + '"', df[col])

df.to_csv("final.csv", sep="|", line_terminator="/\n", header=False, index=False)
```